# Have grep show line numbers with leading zeroes, leading spaces, or padding

Tags: awk, grep

`grep -n ...` prefixes each line with its line number. But the formatting can make the output hard for human interpretation:

```
$ grep -n hello hello.txt
1:hello my dear
5:hello in another line
17:this is a hello in a two-digits line number
20:another hello in the two-digits line realm
3838813:it's a long file and here comes one last hello
```

Is there a way to have `grep` show line numbers in a padded way, for instance with leading zeros or leading spaces?

Example:

```
$ grep -n -$MAGIC hello hello.txt
      1:hello my dear
      5:hello in another line
     17:this is a hello in a two-digits line number
     20:another hello in the two-digits line realm
3838813:it's a long file and here comes one last hello
```

Comment: No. You'll have to pipe the `grep` output to `sed` or `awk` or any other command that can parse the number of characters before the first `:`.

Answer (score 3):

No, there's no way to do what you want with just grep but rather than piping grep output to some other tool like awk for the formatting why not **only** use awk, e.g.:

```
awk '/hello/{printf "%10d:%s\n", FNR, $0}' hello.txt
```

e.g. blank-padded:

```
$ seq 30 | awk '/5/{printf "%10d:%s\n", FNR, $0}'
         5:5
        15:15
        25:25
```

or zero-padded:

```
$ seq 30 | awk '/5/{printf "%010d:%s\n", FNR, $0}'
0000000005:5
0000000015:15
0000000025:25
```

If 10 isn't enough space for the possible line numbers then pick a bigger number or if you want to calculate the field width then you can buffer the matches like [@RavinderSing13 shows in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67253803/1745001). Of course then there's memory and speed of execution hits but that really shouldn't be a problem unless you have literally billions of matches to your regexp in the input.

Answer (score 1):

With single `awk` you could try following. Written and tested in GNU `awk`, should work in any `awk`.

```
awk '
/hello/{
  fnr[++count]=FNR
  val[count]=$0
  max=FNR
}
END{
  fmt="%"length(max)"d:%s\n";
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    printf fmt,fnr[i],val[i]
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

I have tested it with a 350 lines file with `hello` string in between it has given me output like:

```
  1:hello
 20:hello
267:hello
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                       ##Starting awk program from here.
/hello/{                    ##Checking condition if line has hello in it then do following.
  fnr[++count]=FNR          ##Creating line array with count variable it has current line number.
  val[count]=$0             ##Creating val array with index of count which has current line value.
  max=FNR                   ##max is having current line number.
}
END{                        ##Starting END block of this program from here.
  fmt="%"length(max)"d:%s\n";
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){    ##Starting a for loop till count here.
    printf fmt,fnr[i],val[i]  ##Printing line(with fnr array) and val array value, with adding spaces before line number as per OP.
  }
}
' Input_file                ##mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Sir Ji, your answers are quite impressive and I am kind of obsessed the way you explain it always ..

Comment: @Piyush, Thank you for nice words Piyush jee, I try my best to learn and share, cheers. Cheers buddy and happy learning.

Answer (score 1):

another solution

```
$ grep ... | column -ts: | sed -E 's/([0-9]+)( +) /\2\1:/'

       1:hello my dear
       5:hello in another line
      17:this is a hello in a two-digits line number
      20:another hello in the two-digits line realm
 3838813:it's a long file and here comes one last hello
```

`column` to align on delimiter `:` and `sed` to transform left aligned column to right align.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a file, containing some "Errorcodes" and some "Narrowcodes" (the latter just for confirming `grep` is working fine).

The result of the `grep` without the formatting is (command `grep -i -n "Error" test.txt`):

```
1:Errorcode:null
2:Errorcode:405
3:Errorcode:504
100:Errorcode_100
```

I have created following command:

```
grep -i -n "Error" test.txt | awk -F: '{printf ("%05d\n",$1)}'
```

(This is based on [this other StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182075/add-leading-zeroes-to-awk-variable))
Result:

```
00001
00002
00003
00100
```

As you see, the leading zeroes part is working fine, but I don't know how to show the rest of the line, but it's already a start.

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose of padding the numbers is to sort numerically then you can use the option -n from sort command.

cat file | sort -n